# VSCode unbound breakpoints in classes while debugging Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am working on a Node.js project.

I am having problem with debugging codes, that is, some breakpoints become unbounded when I start debugging.

It only occurs in class definition. Another breakpoints that are not in classes work fine.

As I think, because my class methods are not static, breakpoints made in class definition does not works with objects created with the class.

If so, is there good way to debug codes in class methods? Or, If above is not a reason for my problem, should I add some configuration?

Thanks.

Below is some of my codes(`the class file I tried to make breakpoints` and `launch.json`):

1. The class file I tried to make breakpoints

I tried to put breakpoints in next() function, but it did not worked.
(I removed some unnecessary codes from original)

```js
const uniqueArrayByName = require('../tools/uniqueArrayByName')

class paginator {
  constructor(message, promises, step, length, preProcess){
    if(step < 1) throw new Error('a step must be a integer bigger than 0');
    this.message = message;
    this.step = step;
    this.cursor = -step;
    this.promises = promises;
    this.preProcess = preProcess

    this.numberOfCards = length;
  }

  prev(){
    let targetCards = this.cards.slice(this.cursor - this.step, this.cursor);
    this.cursor = this.cursor - this.step;

    return this.showMessages(targetCards);
  }

  async next(){
    this.cursor = this.cursor + this.step;

    if ( !this.cards || this.cursor + this.step >= this.cards.length ) {
      if( this.promises.size > 0 ){
        let res = await promises[0];
        let cards = res.data.cards;
        
        cards = this.preProcess(cards);
        this.cards = uniqueArrayByName(this.cards.concat(cards));
        this.promises = this.promises.slice(1);
      }
    }
    let targetCards = this.cards.slice(this.cursor, this.cursor + this.step);

    return this.showMessages(targetCards);
  }

  
  get getCardsLength(){
    return this.cards.length;
  }

  get getCursor(){
    return this.cursor;
  }
}

module.exports = paginator;
```

2. launch.json

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "pwa-node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/../helloworld/app.js",
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--preserve-symlinks"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out my problem : I just reinstalled VSCode, and it worked. Seems like some files were broken.